# apkanalyzer cannot parse the version name of my app

Tags: android, apk, android-manifest

In a pipeline, I would like to extract from an APK I build the following information:

- the version name of my app
- the version code of my app
- the application id of my app

According to [this documentation](https://developer.android.com/studio/command-line/apkanalyzer), I can use the apkanalyzer command line tool in order to extract these information from my APK file.

First, I tried to get all these information with this commande line:

```
./apkanalyzer apk summary 'my.apk'
```

But the result is not the one I expect:

> unknown 0 ?

So, I tried to use the `manifest` verb instead of the `apk` one:

```
./apkanalyzer manifest version-code 'my.apk'
```

> 2011100022

The result is the one I want. So I tried:

```
./apkanalyzer manifest application-id 'my.apk'
```

> com.my.package

The result is the one I want too. To finish, I tried:

```
./apkanalyzer manifest version-name 'my.apk'
```

> ?

As you can, the result is not the one I want.

I laso tried to display the whole manifest using the command line:

```
./apkanalyzer manifest print 'my.apk'
```

In the result, into the `<manifest />` tag, I can see the following attributes and values:

- `android:versionCode="2011100022"`
- `android:versionName="1.5.6-API-29"`
- `package="com.mypackage`

So as you see, all the needed information are correctly displayed into the manifest.

Note that the APK is a release one and all the information are also correctly displayed in the "apkanalyzer UI tools" in Android Studio:

[image]

So my question is: how can I display correctly the version name of my app using the apkanalyzer command line?